# How do I protect index.php with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I am trying to protect an index.php page of a subfolder with .htaccess.

The protection works as expected when I navigate to `example.com/subfolder/index.php`. However, when I just go to `example.com/subfolder` I get a 401 error.

Here is the relevant .htacess code:

```
AuthUserFile /home/myfolder/subfolder/.htpasswd

AuthName "Please enter your password"

AuthType Basic

<files index.php>
  require valid-user
</files>
```

What do I need to do differently?

Comment: what do you mean by `protect` ? use username & password to authenticate visitor, you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put a new .htaccess file in the `subfolder` directory with just the following in it:

```
AuthUserFile /home/myfolder/subfolder/.htpasswd
AuthName "Please enter your password"
AuthType Basic

require valid-user
```

That will password protect the entire directory

Comment: I think the OP wants to authorize the folder, only exclude the index.php

Comment: Does anyone have a solution that answers the original question? I am still looking for that answer: i.e. How to password protect index.php *only* (not the entire directory) and not get the server error if the user uses "http://site.com/directory" instead of "http://site.com/directory/index.php"